# Copying non existing rows from one database table to another database table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have the following 1 db table in Database 1 and 1db table in Database 2, now the stucture of both tables are exactly the same. Now what happens is table 1 (DB1) gets new rows added daily, I need to update the table 1 (DB 1) new rows in table 1 (DB 2) so that these 2 tables remain the same. A cron will trigger a php script on midnight to do this task. What is the best way to do this and how using PHP/mysql?

Comment: Are rows ever deleted from the first database and do these deletions also need to be reflected in the second database?  Also, do you have a unique key for the table?

Comment: Rows are never deleted ever there are no unique keys

Answer (score 1):

You might care to have a look at replication (see http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.4/en/replication-configuration.html). That's the 'proper' way to do it; it isn't to be trifled with, though, and for small tables the above solutions are probably better (and certainly easier).

Answer (score 0):

This might help you out, its what i do on my database for a similar kinda thing

```
    $dropSQL = "DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `$targetTable`";
    $createSQL = "CREATE TABLE `$targetTable` SELECT * FROM `$activeTable`";
    $primaryKeySQL = "ALTER TABLE `$targetTable` ADD PRIMARY KEY(`id`)";
    $autoIncSQL = "ALTER TABLE `$targetTable` CHANGE `id` `id` INT( 60 ) NOT NULL  AUTO_INCREMENT";
    mysql_query($dropSQL);
    mysql_query($createSQL);
    mysql_query($primaryKeySQL);
    mysql_query($autoIncSQL);
```

obviously you will have to modify the taget and active table variables.  Dropping the table will lose the primary key when you do this, oh well .. easy enough to add back in

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend replication as has already been suggested. However, another option is to use `mysqldump` to grab the rows you need and send them to the other table.

```
mysqldump -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOST --compact -t --where="date=\"CURRENT_DATE\"" DB1 TABLE | mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOST -D DB2
```

Replace `USER`, `HOST`, and `PASSWORD` with login info for your database. You can use different information for each part of the command if `DB1` and `DB2` have different access information. `DB1` and `DB2` are the names of your databases, and `TABLE` is the name of the table.

You can also modify the `--where` option to grab only the rows which need to updated. Hopefully you have some query you can use. As mentioned previously, if the table has a primary key, you could grab the last key which `DB2` has using a command something like

```
KEY=`echo "SELECT MAX(KEY_COLUMN) FROM TABLE;" mysql -uUSER -pPASSWORD -hHOST -D DB2`
```

for a bash shell script (then use this value in the `WHERE` clause above). Depending on how your primary key is generated, this may be a bad idea since rows may be added in holes in the keyspace if they exist.

This solution will also work if rows are changed as long as you have a query which can select these rows. Just add the `--replace` option to the `mysqldump` command. In your situation, it would be best to add some type of value such as date updated which you can compare by.